# Windows ping in C with individual IP address input

Tags: c, windows, cmd

I'm still relatively new to programming and have decided to create an emergency tool in C as a project for general problems in Windows. In addition I would like to create a menu with different problems, which should be selectable.

Problem one would be e.g. that a server/client cannot be reached. Then a ping and a tracert should be triggered in CMD. But my challenge is that I can't get an individual IP address with every query to be entered. And the result should also displayed. Does somebody has any idea?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

#define buffer[BUFFER_SIZE] = { 0 };

int main()
{
    int selection1;

    printf("What is the problem? Type in the appropriate number and press Enter: \n");

    printf("1) Something is unavailable.\n");
    printf("2) Problem 2\n");
    printf("3) Problem 3\n");
    printf("4) Problem 4\n");
    printf("5) Problem 5\n");
    printf("6) Problem 6\n");
    printf("7) Problem 7\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%d", &selection1);

    if (selection1 == 1)
    {
 
        fflush(stdout);
        char* pingAdress;
        scanf("%c", &pingAdress)
        system( "ping %c", pingAdress)
        
    }
```

Comment: 'project for general problems in Windows' => this screams "Powershell" to me. Any interest in switching the language ?

Comment: First of all, `pingAdress` is *uninitialized*. Secondly, it's a *pointer* to a `char` not a single `char` itself. Thirdly `&pingAdress` is a pointer to the pointer of type `char **`.  Fourthly, the `system` function isn't a formatting function like `snprintf`. Fifthly, `%c` is for single characters and not strings. Sixtly (or whatever) the `%c` format for `scanf` will read *all* characters, including whitespace (which includes the newlines from previous inputs). All in all it seems you have skipped some very basic parts of your C text-books or classes.

Comment: @nick Yeah I know powershell will be here the best option, but I want to learn C :)

Comment: @SergejWozke: Fair enough :) My suggestion then: Split your task in two: (a) write a small console programm with user selection and some computation (maybe a "guess the number" game or such), and (b) try to get the ````system()```` stuff to run in a 'naked' environment. If both works as expected, merge them.

Comment: @Some programmer dude: Seems I have a lot of problems there. I've only been learning the language for two weeks. Would you mind showing me an example of how to do it properly? At least then I have a solution. Nick: Thank you, I will try that definitely .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how to do your `ping` use case.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    int selection1;

    printf("What is the problem? Type in the appropriate number and press Enter: \n");

    printf("1) Something is unavailable.\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%d", &selection1);

    if (selection1 == 1)
    {
 
        fflush(stdout);
        char pingAdr[100], pingCmd[100];
        printf("Enter host address: ");
        scanf("%s", pingAdr);
        sprintf(pingCmd, "ping -c 5 %s", pingAdr);
        system(pingCmd);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and solution. In any case, I was able to better understand where my problems were. It works as it should, thank you!